# MySQL Non Index Queries Analysis

Tags: mysql

I'm using the log queries not using index but it logs all that use indexes but just more advanced or using IFs.

Is there a parser or a program out there that can analyze the log and give me a literal output of saying "table.column should be a index"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is a developer who decides where to add indexes and where not to. Because every index decreases write performance (e.g. INSERT/UPDATE) and also requries some storage space. There is no magic program, that will magically design indexes for you.